# Expected value of parametrized Gibbs distribution w.r.t another probability distribution

Tags: measure-theory, statistical-physics, probability-distributions, sampling

Let $\mu$ be a **compactly supported** probability measure on a finite-dimensional euclidean space (for simplicity) $\mathbb E$, and suppose $\mu$ **has density**. For a random point $x \sim \mu$,
consider the Boltzmann distribution at temperature $T$, on $N$ states, viz

$$p_j(x; T) = \frac{\exp(-\frac{1}{T}E_j(x))}{\sum_{l=1}^N\exp(-\frac{1}{T}E_l(x))},$$

where energies $E_j(x) = x^Ty_j + c_j$ is the energy at state $j$, and $y_1,\ldots,y_N \in \mathbb E$, $c_1,\ldots, c_N \in \mathbb R$ are fixed.

## Question

- What can be said about the expectation integral
  $$e_j^\mu(T) := \int p_j(x; T) d\mu(x) $$
- Is it a known quantity / transform ?
- Is there an efficient way to compute $e_j^\mu(T)$ which is "cheaper" (in the sense faster convergence / lower variance of
- estimates) than just sampling $x_1,\ldots, x_M \sim \mu$ and
  computing the empirical mean $\frac{1}{M}\sum_{i=1}^M p_j(x_i;T)$ ?

For the last two questions, for convenience one may assume $T \rightarrow 0^+$ (low-temperature limit). In the high-temperature limit, it's not hard to show that $e_j^\mu(\infty) = N^{-1},\; \forall j=1,\ldots,N$.

Comment: the method you're looking for is [importance sampling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Importance_sampling)

Comment: Thanks. I'll dig in the direction of importance sampling.